# Understanding AWS EMR Behavior with Spot Instances and Failed Queries Despite 'Completed' Status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, spot-instances

I run KPI aggregation queries every morning using AWS EMR. Since I am using spot instances, there are times when the servers are forcibly terminated due to resource shortages. In such cases, the EMR cluster status shows "Canceled," and I address this by re-executing the EMR. The status for each instance shows "Spot instance was terminated due to not enough capacity in the Spot instance pool," and no additional instances are added.

Recently, I noticed unusual behavior with EMR.
The EMR cluster status shows "Completed," but the logs indicate that some queries have failed. Normally, I set up the EMR configuration with one master node and three core (slave) nodes. In this instance, the initial three nodes were forcibly terminated due to insufficient resources, showing "Spot instance was terminated due to not enough capacity in the Spot instance pool." However, I discovered that three additional instances of the same type were launched. So, in total, six instances were used (excluding the master node).
My guess is that the initial three core nodes were forcibly terminated due to resource shortages, and three new instances were allocated, but the task handover failed, resulting in query failures, yet the status showed "Completed."

**My question is whether the addition of these three core node instances is related to the AutoScaling setting in the EMR cluster configuration. Also, is there a setting to prevent automatic addition of instances?**

Regarding EMR Cluster Configuration:

・ServiceRole is set to EMR_DefaultRole.
・JobFlowRole is set to EMR_EC2_DefaultRole.
・AutoScalingRole is set to EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole.
・The master node is set to one "m5.xlarge," and the core nodes to three "c5.24xlarge."
・Using EMR=5.28.0, Hadoop=2.8.5, Hive=2.3.6, Presto=0.227

Note:

・The query content is not the issue.
・Server logs are recorded but cannot be shared.
・The EMR cluster configuration file is not available for sharing.
・I have checked the instance usage with "Spot Instance Advisor" and found no issues.

This is my first post, and I apologize for any inconvenience in my writing. I would greatly appreciate any insights or advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I noticed unusual behavior with EMR. The EMR cluster status shows "Completed," but the logs indicate that some queries have failed."
What's [ActionOnFailure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_StepConfig.html) of the step?

Comment: "three new instances were allocated, but the task handover failed, resulting in query failures, yet the status showed "Completed." Where do you store results of the query? Were the results stored? Retries can be enabled on a few levels by default: for example, in Spark and YARN.

Comment: @LioniaVasilev          
         
Thank you for your comment. The text is long, so I will divide it into three parts.   
          
First, the "ActionOnFailure" is set to "TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW".

Comment: @LioniaVasilev        
    
Next, the queries are stored in RDS. Normally, 30 queries are executed over a period of 5 hours. After execution, they are set to be stored in RDS.      
In this case, 20 queries were executed, but the remaining 10 could not be executed due to a lack of resources in the spot instances. Such forced terminations occur frequently. The stderr log contains notes like “Server is shutting down...”, which applies to the initial three instances that were started. In case of a forced termination, it’s not a problem since we manually execute only the failed queries.

Comment: My question is why, after the initial three core nodes (spot instances) were forcibly terminated, another set of three core nodes started. Moreover, when checking the execution history of the EMR cluster, it appears they ran for only about 30 seconds, so it seems unlikely that they executed any queries. Indeed, the stdout indicates that some queries were marked as "fail query", so these instances seem to have just started and then stopped.

Comment: I see. In general, AWS EMR tries to replace reclaimed Spot Instances to sustain the required capacity, so AWS EMR started another three Core nodes, because the cluster capacity was zero and required to be three. Next, I suppose one of two things happened: either Spark had been shutdown before the provisioning of the additional three nodes completed, and when it's completed there was nothing to run, or Spark tried to continue to run the queries on the second set of nodes, but failed.

Comment: Could you please summarise the errors and exceptions that occurred before the Spark was shut down? What error caused it to shut down? Please see pages [How can I access Spark driver logs on an Amazon EMR cluster?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/spark-driver-logs-emr-cluster) and [View log files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html). In the first attempt, the container of the driver is the one with the suffix `_000001`.